# The script fails to grab links from a webpage utilizing the requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the links located in the middle of this [webpage](https://www.nursinghomes.com/) under the title, `By City`, using the requests module.

The script fails miserably. Although the status code is 200, I end up getting nothing on the console.

Here is what I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.nursinghomes.com/'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Referer': 'https://www.nursinghomes.com/',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
}

res = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
for item in soup.select("li > strong > a[class^='text-link']"):
    print(item.get("href"))
```

Expected results (partial):

```
/tx/austin/
/md/baltimore/
/ny/bronx/
/ny/brooklyn/
/il/chicago/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add `print(res.text)` you'll see the following HTML response:

```
... Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 15190006 ...
```

The websites detects the use of a non-browser, and rejects the request, so bs4 does not receive any useful HTML to parse.

You'll need to find a way to trick the website in trusting the request.